# JavaFX stages full-screening on the wrong screen

Tags: java, javafx, multiple-monitors

I need to run a window on each screen that's present and make it full screen, so, I have this code that will create a stage for each screen, place it in the screen and make it full screen:

```
for (Screen screen : Screen.getScreens()) {
    Stage stage = new Stage();

    stage.setX(screen.getBounds().getMinX());
    stage.setWidth(screen.getBounds().getMaxX() - screen.getBounds().getMinX());
    stage.setY(screen.getBounds().getMinY());
    stage.setHeight(screen.getBounds().getMaxY() - screen.getBounds().getMinY());
    stage.setFullScreen(true);
}
```

When I run that, it looks like all windows end up being full-screen on the same screen. If I remove the `setFullScreen` call, I can see each window being created in the appropriate screen. I'm doing this on Microsoft Windows as a desktop stand-alone application.

Any ideas what's going on?

I also tried using `getVisualBounds` and having some margin around the stages so that there's no chance they were outside the bounds of the screen.

Comment: No idea how to fix this, but just a comment: AIUI the full-screen functionality is implemented by hooking into the operating system's native full screen capability. You may need to specify which platform you are on (and check if it behaves the same on different platforms, if possible).

Comment: @James_D: I added a comment about the platform.

Comment: no solution, but some info: when I try this on OSX, the stages show on my 3 different monitors in maximum size, but do not enter fullscreen mode, even if set programmatically. I can switch them to fullscreen by the window controls but not programmatically.

Comment: but i dont understand you, when you remove the `setFullScreen` you get what you want right? if you are asking why the you get all stages created in one screen and made fullscreen, its because that function call uses the default screen. is that what you are asking about?

Comment: @elltz: if I remove the full screen, the stages appear in the appropriate screens, but not in full screen mode. What makes it use the default screen? According to the documentation, full screen should happen in the current screen the window is at.

Comment: What if you do the `setFullScreen()` after the window is shown? `stage.setOnShown(e -> stage.setFullScreen(true));`